# Unknown column 'User.first_name' in 'where clause' cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have `tutor_students` and `users` table. `tutor_students`contains `id`, `tutor_id`, `student_id` and `created`. `users` contain `id`, `user_id`, `role_id`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`. `tutor_students` table is connected table between tutor and student. so tutor can see their student list and can add new student too.

I succeeded to display student list and add new student to tutor student list. but when i want to search student, there will be an error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'User.email' in 'where clause'
>
> SQL Query: SELECT `TutorStudent`.`id`, `TutorStudent`.`tutor_id`,
>   `TutorStudent`.`student_id`, `TutorStudent`.`created` FROM
>   `virlen`.`tutor_students` AS `TutorStudent` WHERE
>   `TutorStudent`.`tutor_id` IS NULL AND `User`.`email` LIKE
>   '%ka@mailinator.com%'

My controller:

```
public function admin_tutor_add_student($tutor_id = null) 
{
    $user_list = '';        
    $this->loadModel('TutorStudent');   
    $this->set('title_for_layout','User');  
    $this->User->bindModel(array(
                    'belongsTo'=>array(
                        'Standard'=>array(
                            'className'=>'Standard'
                        ),
                    )
    ),false);

    $this->User->id     =   $tutor_id;
    /*form post and check conditions*/
    // if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) 
    if(!empty($this->request->data) && isset($this->request->data['User']['status1']))
    {   
        // pr($this->request->data);die;
        $action = $this->request->data['User']['pageAction'];
        foreach ($this->request->data['User'] AS $value) {
            if ($value != 0) {
                $ids[] = $value;
            }
        }

        // pr($ids);die;
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) 
        {
            if (!isset($this->request->params['_Token']['key']) || ($this->request->params['_Token']['key'] != $this->request->params['_Token']['key'])) 
            {
                $blackHoleCallback = $this->Security->blackHoleCallback;
                $this->$blackHoleCallback();
            }
            foreach($ids as $id)
            {
                if(!empty($id))
                {
                    if($id != 1)
                    {
                        $shift = array();
                        $shift['TutorStudent']['tutor_id'] = $tutor_id;
                        $shift['TutorStudent']['student_id'] = $id;
                        $this->TutorStudent->save($shift);
                        $this->TutorStudent->id = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash("Tutor has been added successfully", 'admin_flash_good');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'subadmin_tutor',$tutor_id));

        }
    } 

    if (!isset($this->params['named']['page'])) 
    {
        $this->Session->delete('AdminSearch');
    }
    $email = '';
    $first_name = '';
    $role_id = '';
    $status = '';
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) 
    {
        $this->Session->delete('AdminSearch');
        if (isset($this->request->data['User']['first_name']) && $this->request->data['User']['first_name'] != '') 
        {
            $first_name = trim($this->request->data['User']['first_name']);
            $this->Session->write('AdminSearch.first_name', $first_name);               
        }
        if (isset($this->request->data['User']['email']) && $this->request->data['User']['email'] != '') 
        {
            $email = trim($this->request->data['User']['email']);
            $this->Session->write('AdminSearch.email', $email);             
        }

    }

    $filters    =   array('TutorStudent.tutor_id'=>$tutor_id);
    if ($this->Session->check('AdminSearch')) 
    {
        $keywords   =   $this->Session->read('AdminSearch');
        foreach($keywords as $key=>$values)
        {
            if($key == 'email')
            {
                $email = $values;
                $filters[] = array('User.'.$key.' LIKE'=>"%".$values."%");                  
            }
            if($key == 'first_name')
            {
                $first_name = $values;
                $filters[] = array('User.'.$key.' LIKE'=>"%".$values."%");                  
            }
        }
    }

    $my_tutor_list = $this->TutorStudent->find('all',array('conditions'=>$filters));
    if(!empty($my_tutor_list))
    {
        foreach($my_tutor_list as $key=>$value)
        {
            $user_list[] = $value['TutorStudent']['student_id'];
        }
    }

    $this->paginate = array('User' => array(
        'limit' =>Configure::read('App.PageLimit'),
        'order' => array('User.id' => 'DESC'),
        'conditions'=>array('User.id !='=>$user_list,'User.role_id'=>2),
        )); //role_id 2 means student user

    $student_list = $this->paginate('User');

    // pr($student_list);die;
    $this->loadModel('Standard');
    $standards  =   $this->Standard->getStandardList();
    $this->set(compact('standards'));
    $this->set(compact('student_list','tutor_id','standard_id', 'User', 'email', 'first_name'));
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('User', true));
}
```

this is my view file:

```
<?php echo($this->Form->create('User', array('url'=>array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'tutor_add_student'))));?>
            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                <div class="box box-danger">
                    <div class="full box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Search</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">User Email</label>
                                <?php echo($this->Form->input('User.email', array('placeholder'=>"Tutor Email",'label' => false,'value'=>$email, 'div'=>false,'class'=>'form-control'))); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">First Name </label>
                                <?php echo($this->Form->input('User.first_name', array('placeholder'=>"First Name",'label' => false,'value'=>$first_name, 'div'=>false,'class'=>'form-control'))); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <br /><?php echo($this->Form->submit('Search', array('div'=>false, 'class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-left')));?> 
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>

            </div>
         <?php echo($this->Form->end());?>
```

This is my app model for user:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Country
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * @category Model 
 * 
 */
// App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
// App::uses('SessionComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel{

    //public $primaryKey = '_id';

    /**
     * Model name
     * @var string
     * @access public
     */
    var $name = 'User';
    /**
     * Behaviors used by the Model
     *
     * @var array
     * @access public
     */

    var $actsAs = array(
       'Multivalidatable'
    );   


    var $validationSets = array(
        'login'=>   array(
            'email'=>array(
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                    'message'   =>  'Email address is required'
                ),
                'R2'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 50),
                    'message'=>'Email can be maximum 50 characters long.' 
                ),
                'email' =>  array(
                    'rule'  =>  'email',
                    'message'   =>  'Please provide a valid email address.'
                ),
            ),
            'password'=>array(
                'R1'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Password is required.'
                ), 
                'R3'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('minLength', 6),
                    'message'=>'Password must be at least 6 characters long.' 
                ),
                'R4'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 20),
                    'message'=>'Password must be at least 20 characters long.' 
                ),                                      
            ),
        ),
        'add'=> array(
            'first_name'=>array(
                'R1'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'First name is required.'
                ),
                'R2'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 255),
                    'message'=>'First Name can be maximum 255 characters long.' 
                ),
                'characters' => array(
                    'rule'     => array('custom', '/^[a-z]*$/i'),
                    'message'  => 'Alphabet characters only'
                )               
            ),
            'last_name'=>array(
                'R1'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Last name is required.'
                ),
                'R2'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength',255),
                    'message'=>'Last name can be maximum 255 characters long.' 
                ),
                'characters' => array(
                    'rule'     => array('custom', '/^[a-z]*$/i'),
                    'message'  => 'Alphabet characters only'
                )
            ),
            'standard_id'=>array(
                'R1'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Standard is required.'
                )
            ),
            'role_id'=>array(
                'R1'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Role is required.'
                )
            ),
            'specilization'=>array(
                'R1' => array(
                    'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                    'message'   =>  'Specilization is required.'
                ),
                'R2'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 255),
                    'message'=>'Specilization can be 255 characters long.' 
                ),  
            ),
            'phone'=>array(
                'R1' => array(
                    'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                    'message'   =>  'Phone number is required.'
                ),
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule'      => 'numeric',
                    'message'   =>  'Phone number should be numeric'
                ),
                'R2'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('minLength', 8),
                    'message'=>'Phone number shuold be minimum 8 numbers long' 
                ),
                'R3'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 12),
                    'message'=>'Phone number should be maximum 12 numbers long' 
                ),
                /* 'R4'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('CheckPhoneVailidation'),
                    'message'=>'Phone no should be start with 82 to 87.' 
                ),   */
            ),
            'email'=>array(
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                    'message'   =>  'Email address is required'
                ),
                'R2'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 50),
                    'message'=>'Email can be maximum 50 characters long.' 
                ),
                'isUnique'  =>  array(
                    'rule'  =>  'isUnique',
                    'message'   =>  'Email already exists.'
                ),
                'email' =>  array(
                    'rule'  =>  'email',
                    'message'   =>  'Please provide a valid email address.'
                ),
            ),  
            'new_password'=>array(
                'R1'=>array(
                    'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Password is required.'
                ), 
                'R3'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('minLength', 6),
                    'message'=>'Password must be at least 6 characters long.' 
                ),
                'R4'=>array(
                    'rule'=>array('maxLength', 20),
                    'message'=>'Password must be at least 20 characters long.' 
                ),                                      
            ),
            'confirm_password'=>array(
                'identicalFieldValues' => array(
                    'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'new_password'),
                    'message' => 'Password and confirm password mismatch'
                ),
                'R1' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Confirm password is required.'
                )

            ),
            'image' => array(
                'R1' => array(
                    'rule' => array('checkextension'),
                    'message' => 'Please upload only image files'
                )
            ),          
        )

    );
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add user table to select

Comment: can you correct my code please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to contain the `User` model in your `find` query:-

```
$this->TutorStudent->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $filters, 
    'contain' => array('User')
);
```

Comment: Model "TutorStudent" is not associated with model "User" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]

Comment: What associations have you defined on your `TutorStudent` model? Presumably the `tutor_students` table and the `users` table are associated somehow for you to want to be able to do this query.

Comment: i think association table in cakePHP is about 'belongsTo' or 'hasMay' but i dont really understand

Comment: That would be your issue then. I'd recommend reading up on [associating models in CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). Does your `User` model represent both tutors and students?

Answer (score -1):

the from clause should be

```
virlen.tutor_students AS TutorStudent,virlen.users AS User
```

Then your query should be

```
SELECT TutorStudent.id, TutorStudent.tutor_id, TutorStudent.student_id, TutorStudent.created FROM virlen.tutor_students AS TutorStudent,virlen.users AS User WHERE TutorStudent.tutor_id IS NULL AND User.email LIKE '%ka@mailinator.com%'
```

Your code should be

```
$my_tutor_list = $this->TutorStudent->find('all',array('conditions'=>$filters,'contain' => array('User')));
if(!empty($my_tutor_list))
{
    foreach($my_tutor_list as $key=>$value)
    {
        $user_list[] = $value['TutorStudent']['student_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you edit it on the code please? i really confuse right now

Comment: Check @drmonkeyninja

Comment: then there will be an error: Model "TutorStudent" is not associated with model "User" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]

Comment: @wendy Could you show the model classes of User and TutorStudent?

Comment: do you mean the model file of User and TutorStudent?

Comment: Exactly the model files

Comment: i dont have model file for TutorStudent but i have one for User

Comment: Try to post the one for User

Comment: I am not an expert with CakePHP but I think you need some sort of explicit relationship in User model file to the TutorStudent model

Comment: i think association table in cakePHP is about 'belongsTo' or 'hasMay' but i dont really understand

Comment: I would have defined the table in other way.The table strutcture is a little bit more complicated that needed

Answer (score -1):

The table User is not included in the query, you should try something like:

```
SELECT TutorStudent.id, TutorStudent.tutor_id,  TutorStudent.student_id,  TutorStudent.created 
FROM  virlen.tutor_students AS TutorStudent join 
virlen.User as user
on user.id = tutorstudent.student_id
 WHERE TutorStudent.tutor_id IS NULL AND User.email LIKE '%ka@mailinator.com%';
```

This assuming that the User table key used in tutor_student.student_id is id and not user_id, in which case you should change your code consequently to be it like: `on user.user_id = tutorstudent.student_id`